# Http Web Request C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to check if the method logged in or not ..
When I send the request to log in and see the **Response 2** 's Uri .. it doesn't want to be redirected to **mbasic.facebook.com/home.php**

```
    public bool Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mbasic.facebook.com/");
            Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";
            Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            Request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
            string Form = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Regex Regexr = new Regex(@"<form .*<\/form>");
            Form = Regexr.Match(Form).Value;
            string[] parts1 = Form.Split(new string[] { "<input" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (Cookie cookie in Response.Cookies)
            {
                Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            Regexr = new Regex("name=" + '"' + "(.*)" + '"' + " value=" + '"' + "(.*)" + '"');
            string LoginData = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                foreach (Match item in Regexr.Matches(parts1[i]))
                {
                    if (item.Value.Contains("autocomplete") == true)
                    {
                        string[] str2 = item.Groups[2].Value.Split(' ');
                        LoginData += item.Groups[1] + "=" + str2[0] + "&";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LoginData += item.Groups[1] + "=" + item.Groups[2] + "&";
                    }
                }
            }
            Regexr = new Regex(@"\/><ul(.*)");
            LoginData = LoginData.Replace(Convert.ToString('"'), String.Empty).Remove(LoginData.IndexOf(Regexr.Match(LoginData).Value)).Replace("/>", "") + "&email=" + Email + "&pass=" + Pass; ;
            var Request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mbasic.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&lwv=101&refid=8");
            var GetBytesData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(LoginData);
            Request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";
            Request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            Request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Request2.ContentLength = GetBytesData.Length;
            Request2.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            Request2.CookieContainer = Cookies;
            using (var StreamR = Request2.GetRequestStream())
            {
                StreamR.Write(GetBytesData, 0, GetBytesData.Length);
            }
            var Response2 = (HttpWebResponse)Request2.GetResponse();
            Cookies = Request2.CookieContainer;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            //the error is here
            if (Response2.ResponseUri.ToString().Contains("home.php")==true)
            {
                var Request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mbasic.facebook.com/profile.php");
                Request3.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";
                Request3.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                Request3.CookieContainer = Cookies;
                var Response3 = (HttpWebResponse)Request3.GetResponse();
                string Form2 = new StreamReader(Response3.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Regexr = new Regex("<strong class=" + '"' + "profileName" + '"' + @">(.*)<\/strong>");
                UserName = Regexr.Match(Form2).Groups[1].Value;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(UserName);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you step through the method? What you mean by "it doesn't want to be redirected"? Are you getting an error? If so, enter the error in your question. If no error occurs, step through the program and tell us what you want to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: Facebook terms forbid using any such automated tools. If you want to interact with users, pages or content on Facebook  - use their API.

Comment: yes i did .. go to the line where i declared the var Request2 
in this line i created a web request to "https://mbasic.facebook.com/login.php..."
when i got the response.. it didn't log into facebook.. if it logged
the uri would be "https://mbasic.facebook.com/home.php"
got it ?

Comment: CBroe... i'm learning how to use http web request